# Build Qt from source so that it accepts Chinese input

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian, chinese-locale

I build Qt from source on Debian buster but now I cannot input Chinese on a QLineEdit. Chinese input works for all other applications execpt the one I build with that Qt I build from source. If I build my application with that Qt from apt get then Chinese input works fine.

I compiled with following command:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-5.12.8/configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -static -opensource -qt-xcb -confirm-license -skip qtwebengine -feature-freetype -fontconfig -no-icu -nomake tests -nomake examples
```

And I check Chinese input with a simple project like:

```
QMainWindow w;
QLineEdit lineEdit;
w.setCentralWidget(&lineEdit);
w.show();
```

Any suggestion on what should I look for?

Comment: QLineEdit has a locale member which should be taken from the environment if your program is written correctly.

Comment: What happens when you paste Chinese characters into this edit? Maybe problem is keyboard handling? Or maybe problem is font which do not support Chinese. Your minimal example should just work. Try drop `-fontconfig` when configuring Qt.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-embedded-fonts.html

Comment: I was able to paste Chinese characters. I tried drop `-fontconfig` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my qt application loads a bunch of plugins when it starts. One of those plugins talks to the OS IME i.e. fcitx or ibus, etc...

I found out I was using fcitx and apt get provided qt have a plugin for that - that's why Chinese input was working. On the other hand my qt build from source does not have fcitx plugin, but have plugin for ibus.

So I removed fcitx and installed ibus and now I can type Chinese on my qt application build with qt build from source.

However, I still don't know why apt get provided qt have fcitx plugin and my qt build don't.